# Ruby associative array calculation

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have an associative array in ruby which I want to convert into a hash. This hash will represent the first values as key and sum of their second values as its value.

```
 x =   [[1,2],[1,3],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,5],[0,4],[1,6],[0,9],[1,9]]
```

How can I get a hash like the following from this associative array?

```
{
  :0 => <sum_of_second_values_with_0_as_first_values>,
  :1 => <sum_of_second_values_with_1_as_first_values>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very beautiful but it works.

```
x =   [[1,2],[1,3],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,5],[0,4],[1,6],[0,9],[1,9]]

p Hash[
   x.group_by(&:first)
   .map do |key, val|
     [key,val.map(&:last).inject(:+)]
   end
] # => {1=>25, 0=>19}
```

On second thought, this is simpler:

```
result = Hash.new(0)
x.each{|item| result[item.first] += item.last}
p result # => {1=>25, 0=>19}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I rewrote this in a more ruby-elegant way,     x.inject( Hash.new(0)){ |h,e| h[e[0]] += e[1]; h }

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution using reduce.
It starts with an empty Hash and iterates over all elements of `x`.
For each pair it adds its value to the hash element at `key` (if this index wasn't set before, default is 0). The last line sets the memory variable `hash` for the next iteration.

```
x.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, pair|
    key, value = pair
    hash[key] += value
    hash
}
```

EDIT: set hash default at initialization

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [[1,2],[1,3],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,5],[0,4],[1,6],[0,9],[1,9]]
arr_0,arr_1 = x.partition{|a,b| a==0 }
Hash[0,arr_0.map(&:last).inject(:+),1,arr_1.map(&:last).inject(:+)]
# => {0=>19, 1=>25}
```

or

```
x =   [[1,2],[1,3],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,5],[0,4],[1,6],[0,9],[1,9]]
hsh = x.group_by{|a| a.first}.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(k,v),h|
    h[k]=v.map(&:last).inject(:+)
end
hsh
# => {1=>25, 0=>19}
```

Comment: If he has 100 keys he need 100 lines. Not a very general answer.

Comment: @hirolau Hummm so I added a new one also.. :)

Answer (score 1):

[`each_with_object`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) also works

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,5],[0,4],[1,6],[0,9],[1,9]].
each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(first,last), h| h[first] += last }
# => {1=>25, 0=>19}
```